# Bind .on to function in jquery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, undefined

> > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
> >     at HTMLButtonElement. (myFile.js:84)
> >     at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:7)
> >     at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:7)

I've tried to do something like this, in modal I have a form, and when you have some unsaved info I wanted to open small bootbox alert via CancelSave function, but the form and modal to stay in the background, this works but there's an error in chrome, how can I get rid of it, or try to attach this "show.bs.modal" to my function the other way?

```
$("#cancelButton").click(function () {
    CancelSave().on("show.bs.modal");
    return false;
});

function CancelSave() {
    return bootbox.dialog({
        backdrop: true,
        closeButton: true,
        show: false,
        title: "Unsaved Information",
        message: "Would you like to save",
        buttons: {
            cancel: {
                label: "CANCEL",
                className: "",
                callback: function () { }
            },
            danger: {
                label: "NO",
                className: "",
                callback: function () { }
            },
            main: {
                label: "YES",
                className: "btn-primary",
                callback: function () {
                    Save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your function doesn't return anything, it will return `undefined`, thus the error you're facing.

Comment: CancelSave function has bootbox.dialog({... in it

Comment: Show the code of `CancelSave` function

Comment: @Satpal edited...